# Copy the same files to two drives / synchronize with a source

Tags: windows, backup, file-transfer

I wish to make backups by copying the same files from a source to two external USB drives as well as synchronize with the source.

The idea of a backup here is to be able to store a second drive in another location to keep it safe.

What is a good way to do this?

Comment: Perhaps a RAID setup?

Comment: @EricF RAID is a possibility but the idea of the backup here is the ability to store one of the drives in another location to keep it safe.

Comment: You just want the most efficient way of copying then right? As I see you are in windows you can simply look up the appropriate dos command to copy then

Answer (score 1):

Software recommendations are off topic here but I do exactly what you are describing via the free version of [Crash Plan](https://www.crashplan.com/en-us/download/)

Essentially  backup to a local USB drive and than I run Crash Plan on another PC with USb drive attached in a different location, which gives me a cheap (free) offsite backup and when I modify the files on the source, both locations get automatically updated.

Comment: Thank you @TomEus. What is an appropriate SE site for software recommendations btw?